# How to get value of every single row on mouseover through JQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is my HTML markup:

```
<article class="container content col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
      <div class="x_panel well">
        <div class="x_content">
          <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody></tbody>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
  </article>
```

I have populated this table using the JSON data below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  function init_DataTables()
    {
      console.log('run_datatables');

      if( typeof ($.fn.DataTable) === 'undefined'){ return; }
      console.log('init_DataTables');

      var handleDataTableButtons = function() {
        if ($("#datatable-buttons").length){
          $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({
                                              dom: "Bfrtip",
                                              buttons: [
                                                  {
                                                      extend: "copy",
                                                      className: "btn-sm"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      extend: "csv",
                                                      className: "btn-sm"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      extend: "excel",
                                                      className: "btn-sm"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      extend: "pdfHtml5",
                                                      className: "btn-sm"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      extend: "print",
                                                      className: "btn-sm"
                                                  },
                                              ],
                                              "aaData": [
                                                  {
                                                      "Name": "Tiger Nixon",
                                                      "Position": "System Architect",
                                                      "Office": "$320,800",
                                                      "Age": "2011/04/25",
                                                      "Start date": "Edinburgh",
                                                      "Salary": "5421"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      "Name": "Garrett Winters",
                                                      "Position": "Accountant",
                                                      "Office": "$170,750",
                                                      "Age": "2011/07/25",
                                                      "Start date": "Tokyo",
                                                      "Salary": "8422"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      "Name": "Ashton Cox",
                                                      "Position": "Junior Technical Author",
                                                      "Office": "$86,000",
                                                      "Age": "2009/01/12",
                                                      "Start date": "San Francisco",
                                                      "Salary": "1562"
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      "Name": "Cedric Kelly",
                                                      "Position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
                                                      "Office": "$433,060",
                                                      "Age": "2012/03/29",
                                                      "Start date": "Edinburgh",
                                                      "Salary": "6224"
                                                  }
                                              ],
                                              "aoColumns": [
                                                  { "mData": "Name" },
                                                  { "mData": "Position" },
                                                  { "mData": "Office" },
                                                  { "mData": "Age" },
                                                  { "mData": "Start date" },
                                                  { "mData": "Salary" }
                                              ],
                                              responsive: true
                                            });
        }
      };

      TableManageButtons = function()
        {
          "use strict";
          return {
          init: function() {
            handleDataTableButtons();
          }
          };
        }();

      $('#datatable-scroller').DataTable({
        ajax: "js/datatables/json/scroller-demo.json",
        deferRender: true,
        scrollY: 380,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        scroller: true
      });

      var $datatable = $('#datatable-checkbox');

      $datatable.dataTable({
        'order': [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        'columnDefs': [
        { orderable: false, targets: [0] }
        ]
      });

      $datatable.on('draw.dt', function()
        {
          $('checkbox input').iCheck({
          checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green'
          });
        });
      TableManageButtons.init();
    };

  init_DataTables();
});
```

What I am trying to do is I want to get the value which is present in the name field for that specific row and perform an operation on that row. I am using the below jQuery code but its showing undefined.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#datatable-buttons tbody tr', function()
        {
            alert($(this).data('Name'));
        });
```

How to get the value of a specific field of each field when mouse is over the tr field

Comment: **How to get the value of a specific field of each field when mouse is over thr tr field** which specific field of which field?

Comment: There is a name field present in which there are persons name on each row. Lets assume i do a mouseover on 1st row then i want the name which is present on the row 1st name field and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code works it is okay. However, for future readers I would like to recommend some corrections.

**Overcooked selector**
The selectors in `$(document).on('mouseover', '#datatable-buttons tbody tr',` is overcooked.  It becomes a delegated event upon the overall `document` where all you need is

```
$('#datatable-buttons').on('mouseover', 'tbody tr',
```

Delegating events to `document` means the parser needs to travel through much more elements == slower execution. `document` should only be used as a substitute when you are not sure the parent element really exists when the handler is declared.

**Bloated data retrieval**
`$(this).children(":first").text()` is a little bit overcooked as well. You convert the `tr` to a jQuery instance, then enumerate *all* its children, then using `:first` to get only the extracted *text* content for one column.

You have a huge optimised dataTables API on your hand. If you are not storing the dataTable instance by `table = $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({..})` then you always have access to the API on an instantiated dataTable by using `var table = $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable();`

A dataTable `tr` always have a property named `_DT_RowIndex` which is the rows unique index. The API have a lot of [**`cell`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) methods to access or manipulate individual cells.

So here is what I would recommend :

```js
$('#datatable-buttons').on('mouseover', 'tbody tr', function() {
  var row = this._DT_RowIndex;
  var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable();
  console.log ('col #1 ', table.cell( row, 0 ).data() );
  console.log ('col #2 ', table.cell( row, 1 ).data() );  
  console.log ('col #3 ', table.cell( row, 2 ).data() );
  console.log ('col #4 ', table.cell( row, 3 ).data() );
  console.log ('col #5 ', table.cell( row, 4 ).data() );
  console.log ('col #6 ', table.cell( row, 5 ).data() );
})
```

Faster event.handling, faster data retrieval and more readable and maintain friendly code.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/kx6grj2q/**

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer for this and this is the code:

```
alert($(this).children(":first").text());
```

So the my whole new code will be like

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#datatable-buttons tbody tr', function()
    {
        alert($(this).children(":first").text());
    });
```

Reference: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/28573/how-can-i-get-a-cell-value-when-i-select-a-table-row